# Running two functions with threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class with name Socket that have tow function for example func1 and func2

```
fucn1() {
    while(true) {
        ...
    }
}

fucn2() {
    while(true) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want two of them run with thread in a time and concurrently. how can i do that??

```
class socket implement Runnable {
    public void run() {
        func1();
        func2();
    }
}
```

In this code only first function is executed not second. How can i do for concurrently run both of them?

Comment: Are both methods returning void and taking no parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Suggestion is :

Instead of making socket `Class` `Runnable`, 
Create two `Runnable` threads as in my example below and call your functions from there. And start these two threads from your `Socket` class.

```
class Socket{
    private void startThreads() {
          new Thread(new Th1()).start();
          new Thread(new Th2()).start();

    }
}
class Th1 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fucn1();
    }
}
class Th2 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fucn2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use capital letters for naming classes (Th1, Th2) because it is Java convention. I also don't know know why you wait 100 miliseconds after calling the func1() and func2() functions? Guess it's just my ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

You can run them concurrently like this:

```
// start a thread for func1
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { 
           func1();
       }
    });
 t1.start();

 // func2 will run in parallel on the main thread
 func2();

 t1.join(); // if you want to wait for func1 to finish.
```

You haven't given any details, so I'm assuming they have no side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the two functions concurrently, spawn two threads and run each function in its own thread.

That's precisely what threads are for.

Comment: @mehdi: I'd start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two threads for this scenario.

```
class socket implement runable
{
    boolean condition;

    public socket(boolean condition){
         this.condition = condition;
    }
    public void run()
   {
      if(condition == true){
            func1();
      }else{
           func2();        
      }
   }
}

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Socket(true));
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Socket(false));


  t1.start();
    t2.start();
```

In addition to this you need to yield control in each method just to make sure that every thread will get fair chance to run.